# Convert XML to JSON, can't find working method(XML.toJSONObject) doesn't work?

Tags: android, xml, json

I'm trying in my app to convert some XML file that i've gathered from a webservice, into JSON. But i can't figure out how. I've seen tons of example's on google doing something simlar to this ;

```
JSONObject jO = new JSONObject();
String xml = "woop";
jO = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
```

And I can't seem to find the XML? When I do like this, it just tells me I need to create a class called XML. And when I try to manually import XML from org.json, I can't find it. I only see 4 choices, whereas XML isn't included.

Is there any other quick way to do this, or am I just missing something important since I can't figure out how this goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to download the java-json lib and include it in your project. You can use this link to find a downloadable jar:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

From there you can use one of the methods mentioned in many other posts, for example:

```
JSONObject myJson = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
```